# Tag merge / synonym request: [optimisation] -> [optimization]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-merge

Please merge or create a synonym for [optimisation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimisation) and [optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization).

[Both appear to be valid](http://painintheenglish.com/case/920/sort:PostComment.score/direction:desc/) writings depending on the spelling (British/American English), but their meaning (and therefore tag definition) are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been done. 1 question was affected by this merge.